# Does not work python curses's getstr() on mac

Tags: python, curses

I'm using the curses library in python 3.9.1 on mac.

I tried this code.

```
import curses


def main(stdscr):
    stdscr.move(0, 0)
    stdscr.addstr('Hello')
    stdscr.refresh()
    stdscr.move(0, 0)
    stdscr.addstr(str(len(stdscr.getstr(0, 0, 3).decode(encoding='utf-8'))))
    stdscr.refresh()

    while True:
        pass


curses.wrapper(main)
```

i expected '3ello'. but the output was only 'Hello'.

why?

[img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bmmCK.png)

or do you have other methods to get raw texts on the screen?

Comment: You are calling `addstr()` with an integer parameter, rather than a string - that simply isn't valid, I'm surprised you're not getting an error.  Put `str(...)` around the parameter, and it should work.

Comment: oh, You are right. That's my mistake. Thank you. but can't work ;) output only 'hello'